# sed + delete duplicate lines except the first one according to specific request

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, sed, awk

in `/etc/services` file I can see duplicate lines

for example

the following line is duplicate ( or more )

```
odasrv         2432/udp
```

so it can easily deleted by sed as the follwing

```
  sed  -i '/codasrv         2432\/udp/d' /etc/services
```

but the problem is that sed delete all this duplicate lines

so what I need to  change in the `sed` syntax

in order to delete all duplicate lines except the first one ?

Comment: `man uniq`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix

Comment: I want to delete line according to specific request , I not want to delete all duplicate lines  , second thing the empty lines in the file must be saved as is without deletion empty lines ,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix and use `sed -i` to edit the file inplace.